# Including antlr4 c++ runtime using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to use [antlr4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) in my C++ project. I want to add the [antlr4 cpp runtime](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/runtime/Cpp) as a dependency in CMake, but I am not sure how to proceed. The [official tutorial](https://github.com/blorente/antlr-4.7-cpp-cmake-base) uses old CMake syntax, and I am looking for something based on targets.

I was thinking about using Git submodules to download all of antlr4 and then use `add_subdirectory` to only include what I needed (antlr4/runtime/Cpp). However, that would force my users to download the entire source. Git clone has had a "filter" option since v2.19, but I don't think that's available for subdmodules.

I have been using [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) in the past, which was cleaner than submodules imho. However, I am not sure how that would work here, since I do not want to download the entire repo and the CMakeLists.txt file is not in the base folder.

How could I include the antlr4 C++ runtime to my project using modern cmake practices?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the exact same issue.

After a while of digging, and since no feasible alternative seemed to exist (except for adding the whole repository and just link to the runtime part, which is what you were trying to avoid), I created a standalone repository with the necessary runtime files to compile and link to, plus support for CMake target linking.

In case it is still useful somehow, take a look at it [here](https://github.com/adeharo9/antlr4-cpp-runtime).